# Brainf**k Interpreter in LaTeX

Tags: programming

Is there a way to build an interpreter for LaTeX to Brainf**k?

A short introduction on how to tackle the task would be appreciated.

Comment: I thought the general view was that TeX was its own special brand of [brainfuck](http://ctan.org/pkg/xii)....

Comment: https://github.com/blefloch/latex-runner/blob/master/runner-brainfuck.dtx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a TeX implementation of such an interpreter here

https://github.com/blefloch/latex-runner/blob/master/runner-brainfuck.dtx